# Generic custom CodeActivity which allows any type?

Tags: c#, android-activity, workflow

Any one help me out i would like to add my collection which is of any type. I need this to build a custom CodeActivity.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you are trying to do and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just typecast your stuff to objects and use a `List<object>` like this:

```
string myString = "foo";
int number = 100;
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(myString);
list.Add(number);
```